# How can I grab an item from a collection in a serializable class?

Tags: java, arrays, sqlite, serialization

I have something like this(Very simplified version):

```
 public class TransferData implements Serializable{

  private Collection[] collections;
  private String ID;

  public TransferData( Collection[] collections){
   this.ID = ID;
   this.collections = collections;

  }

  public String getID(){
        return ID;
  }

  public Collection[] getCollections(){
        return collections;
  }

}
```

This is how I usually grab an item:

```
//Save object in db
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("id", td.getID());
```

However, I am having trouble understanding how to grab an item from a collection/array in a serializable class?

This doesn't make sense:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("collectionitem1", td.getCollections()); ??? //need to index the array, how?
```

I tried something like this:

```
for (int i=0; i <= td.getCollections().length; i++) {
                                System.out.println(i);
                            }
```

but strangely only gives me 3 indices instead of 4 indices that I have in my array but it doesn't help me. Also, my array contains strings and integers, so might be hard to index through with a foreach style loop.

Comment: you should explain of what type `values` is, nobody knows your context

Comment: oh sorry, I mean:  ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! I knew it was something about setting up going through the array incorrectly. Here's the solution:

```
//Create a new map of values, where column names are the keys
                            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

                            for (Collection collection : td.getCollections()) {

                                values.put("reminders", collection.getNumberOfReminders());
                        }
```

Answer (score -1):

I see you're using SQLite.  It seems to me that you're going about this all wrong.  It seems like you need to use Entity Classes:

```
/**
 *
 * @author kkennedy
 */
@Entity(name = "TransferData")
@Table(name = "TransferData")
public class TransferData implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false, length = 8)
    private String ID;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "data", nullable = false, length = 8)
    private String data;

    /**
     * Default Constructor
     */
    public TransferData() {
    }

    /**
     * Getter
     *
     * @return
     */
    public String getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    /**
     * Setter
     *
     * @param ID
     */
    public void setID(String ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    /**
     * Getter
     *
     * @return
     */
    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

    /**
     * Setter
     *
     * @param data
     */
    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

}
```

I'm sure this is not what you would actually use, but by using Entity Classes, the JDBC driver does all the work of actually putting the data into and out of the database.  You just enter it into the class and then persist and query the database, as needed.

Not sure if this is the best place to start, but try here for more info: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbqw.html

Comment: Well the way I am doing it now, the ID and other regular strings not included in this example work. It's just the array doesn't. It could that I am not setting up the array correctly

Comment: Btwm getData is not a simple string. It's a class with other fields